# How to make screenreader not recognise an element as an element group?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

I'm currently trying to make a DOM element with one to several child elements as accessible as possible. The element will contain illustrative content using background images in several layers. I'm currently using a child element for providing the image description as described [in this informative blog post about how to label illustrative content inside of a content group](http://davidmacd.com/blog/alternate-text-for-css-background-images.html). The container element may also contain other child elements containing text content.

An example element would currently look as follows:

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="comic-panel">
  <span role="img" aria-label="There is a cat sitting in the window."></span>
  <div style="background-image: url(/assets/img/window.png);" class="comic-panel__layer"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url(/assets/img/cat.png);" class="comic-panel__layer"></div>
  <p class="speech-bubble">Meow!</p>
</div>
```

Testing with OSX VoiceOver, after tabbing into this element, the image description and the text is read fine, but subsequently, the following announcement is made as well:

[image: You are currently on a group, inside web content. To interact with items in this group, press Control-Option-Shift-Down Arrow. To exit this web area, press Control-Option-Shift-Up Arrow]

Is it possible to update the markup of this element in a way, that this `group` announcement is not made by screenreaders? In almost all cases there will be nothing for the user to further explore or use inside of the element so this message would be redundant and I'd like VoiceOver to not recognise the element as a group that triggers this message.

Comment: can we back up a second?  you have `tabindex="0"` on your <div> but the <div> doesn't have a `role` and is not an interactive element. if you read the `tabindex` specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute), it has a warning that says: *"authors should only make elements focusable if they act as interactive controls"*. so, before we can solve the screen reader text, can you explain a bit more about what the user can **do** with the comic panel?

Comment: My goal with `tabindex="0"` was that the `div` is keyboard accessible, so a user can tab into each `comic-panel` and listen to the text of both the image description and the text elements contained within. Does this answer the question and how can this be improved?

Comment: `"so a user can tab into each comic-panel and listen to the text"`.  so you have some built-in audio files that can be played when the user tabs into the comic panel?  or do you mean a screen reader user can tab into it?  if the later, you don't want to make a non-interactive element keyboard focusable just to allow a screen reader user to hear text.  they already have shortcut keys in the screen reader software itself that will allow them to do that.

Comment: Yes exactly, I mean the latter. Do you happen to know how I can test myself what you're describing with  ` they already have shortcut keys in the screen reader software itself that will allow them to do that`. I'd like to know what the user experience is like, but so far, I've only been testing screen readers by tabbing through websites and I'm not sure yet which shortcuts you're referring to.

Comment: Tabbing through an interface is how a sighted person uses a screen reader. A true screen reader user (or a sighted SR user that's been trained), knows they can use single char shortcuts to navigate to diff types of elements: H for heading, T for table, L for list, B for button, etc. The last one is an interactive element so can be reached with TAB too. The others are pure text but a SR can hear them even without `tabindex=0`. SR user can also up/down arrow to navigate to every element in the DOM.

Comment: JAWS shortcut keys - https://support.freedomscientific.com/training/Surfs-Up/Quick_Keys.htm ; NVDA shortcut keys - https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation ; feel free to contact me directly as noted in my stackoverflow profile if you have other accessibility questions, although posting here with the `accessibility` tag is a great resource.  you should also check https://webaim.org/community/

Comment: Also, the "surf's up" training for JAWS is a great learning tool to understand screen readers - https://support.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-Up/_Surfs_Up_Start_Here.htm.  Even though the training is for JAWS, many of the single character shortcut keys are the same for NVDA so the training will still help.  If there are references to function keys (such as Ins+F5), those keys will be quite different between the two screen readers.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you for the detailed answer to my question and all the resources - the links you posted are super helpful @slugolicious!

Comment: The accessibility community is awesome. People like to help. I will probably copy all my comments to an official answer so you can rate it and/or accept it.

Comment: Yes, that'd be great and thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Moving all my comments from the comment section to the answer section since the discussion in the comments resolved the issue.)*

I think there might be some misunderstanding of how a screen reader (SR) works and how a SR user navigates a webpage.

You have `tabindex="0"` on your <div> but the <div> doesn't have a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) and is not an interactive element.  The [tabindex spec](http://w3.org/tr/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute) has a warning that says:

> "authors should only make elements focusable if they act as interactive controls".

So unless the user can actually interact with the <div>, it should not have `tabindex="0"`.

If the user **can** interact with the <div>, then the <div> will also need a `role` (see previous URL to `role`) so that the SR will announce the element properly and the user will understand how to interact with that element.

For non-interactive elements, SR users have lots of ways to navigate around the page so that they can access other text on the page.

One of the more common ways to navigate is by using the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys to walk the DOM.  (Actually, you're not walking the DOM, per se, but rather the [Accessibility Tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#intro_treetypes), which is basically a subset of the DOM.  For example, hidden elements (CSS `display:none`) are in the DOM but are not in the Accessibility Tree.)

Anyway, the up/down arrow keys let the SR user get to every piece of text on the display.  All your headings, paragraphs, lists, etc.

There are also single letter shortcut keys that allows the SR user to navigate to specific types of elements.  For example,

- <kbd>H</kbd> will take me to the next heading
- <kbd>T</kbd> will take me to the next table
- <kbd>L</kbd> will take me to the next list
- <kbd>B</kbd> will take me to the next button

But these keys will only work if you are using semantic html, such as an <h2>, <table>, <ul>, <button>, etc **or** if you are using the appropriate [ARIA attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes).  For example, if there's a reason you can't use <h2> to make a real heading, you can still tell the SR that you have a heading by using ARIA.

```
<span role="heading" aria-level="2">This is a custom h2 heading</span>
```

JAWS and NVDA are common SRs on the PC.  They'll have similar single key shortcuts that can be seen here:

- [JAWS shortcut keys](http://support.freedomscientific.com/training/surfs-up/quick_keys.htm)
- [NVDA shortcut keys](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation)
- [VoiceOver shortcut keys](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1131.html#cpvokys08) (for the Mac, not iOS).  Note that these are not single key shortcuts, like a simple <kbd>H</kbd>, but require the "VO" key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> by default) in combination with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd>.

Apple has a good [tutorial on VoiceOver](https://help.apple.com/voiceover/mac/10.14/).

For the PC, Freedom Scientific (the maker of JAWS) has a good [tutorial on JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-Up/_Surfs_Up_Start_Here.htm).

If you have questions about accessibility, posting on stackoverflow is certainly one way to go, especially if you tag your question with `accessibility` and other accessibility related tags (such as `wai-aria` or `screen-readers`, as you did on this question).

Another resources is the [WebAIM community](http://webaim.org/community).  Anyone can join and you can "lurk" and just read the discussions as they come in, or fully participate.