# How to prevent Screen Readers read all content in scrollable container?

Tags: screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I have scrollable container, , and when Screen Readers focus on him they read all readable content which they can find.

Thats normall behavior for Screen Readers or i can prevent this?

Comment: Not quite enough info to answer your question.  Do you have an html example?  How are you navigating with the screen reader?

Comment: @slugolicious i have div container with css rule "overflow scroll", thats all. and i use tab to navigate to this container

Comment: using TAB to navigate implies you have an interactive element.  a <div> should not be tabbable (although i think firefox makes containers with scrollbars a tab stop by default.  chrome, safari, and ie do not.  you should add `tabindex="-1"` to the <div> to prevent keyboard focus from moving to the container).  if a screen reader user wants to navigate to some text that is in a container, they can use the up/down arrow keys to navigate all elements in the DOM.

Comment: see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197141/how-to-make-screenreader-not-recognise-an-element-as-an-element-group#answer-55245938 for more details about navigating with a screen reader.